# How to define a event on the ActionBar logo to go back from a helper class

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have activity a, and I want to use the action bar logo to go back.
usually this is done:

```
ActionBar actionBar= getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and to  define the event you usualy have to rewrite the activities 
onOptionsItemSelected(), but what if you want to rewrite this event from a helper class,

I so my code is:

```
class Helper{
    public void init(Activity a) {
    ActionBar actionBar= a.getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ?????? a.onOptionsItemSelected(?MenuItem?)
    }}
```

how do I find the MenuItem object for the actionsBar Logo click

Answer (score 1):

You have to place this in your caller-class:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // DO SOMETHING WHEN BUTTON PRESSED!
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The only way i know of to do it in the helper-class would be to have the helper as a fragment and then use setHasOptionsMenu(true); in that fragment.